# Pyspark mistake: requirement failed: Column must be of type numeric but was actually of type string mistake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I tried to convert pandas dataframe to PySpark format

```
mySchema = StructType([ StructField("movieId", IntegerType())\
                       ,StructField("title", StringType()),
                       StructField("userId", IntegerType()),
                       StructField("rating", FloatType())
                       ])
movielens = spark.createDataFrame(merged_df, mySchema)
movielens.printSchema()
```

Schema

```
root
 |-- movieId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- userId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- rating: float (nullable = true)
```

Then prepared my data for the model

```
(train_set,temp) = movielens.randomSplit([8.0,1.0],seed=1)
validation_set = (temp.join(train_set,["userId"],"left_semi").join(train_set,["movieId"],"left_semi"))
removed = (temp.join(validation_set,["movieId","userId"],"left_anti"))
train_set = train_set.union(removed)
als = ALS(
        userCol = "userId",
        itemCol = "movieId",
        ratingCol = "rating"
)
evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(
    metricName = "rmse",
    labelCol = "rating", 
    predictionCol = "prediction"
)

model = als.fit(train_set)
predictions = model.transform(validation_set)
```

And got that mistake

```
IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column userId must be of type numeric but was actually of type string.
```

How is this possible, cause I've written types manually in MySchema?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: try `train_set.printSchema()` to confirm the datatype?

Comment: nothing changed. the types of columns remained same

Comment: @Lina did you manage to solve this? I am experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have `NaN`/missing values which are difficult to evaluate using the `RegressionEvaluator` . This implies the cold start problem

You may continue by specifying drop as the cold start strategy.

```py
als = ALS(
        userCol = "userId",
        itemCol = "movieId",
        ratingCol = "rating",
        coldStartStrategy = "drop"
)
```

I've included an excerpt from the spark docs which expounds on how spark handles this issue.

#### [Spark Cold-Start strategy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/ml-collaborative-filtering.html#cold-start-strategy)

> When making predictions using an ALSModel, it is common to encounter
> users and/or items in the test dataset that were not present during
> training the model. This typically occurs in two scenarios:
>
> In production, for new users or items that have no rating history and
> on which the model has not been trained (this is the “cold start
> problem”). During cross-validation, the data is split between training
> and evaluation sets. When using simple random splits as in Spark’s
> CrossValidator or TrainValidationSplit, it is actually very common to
> encounter users and/or items in the evaluation set that are not in the
> training set By default, Spark assigns NaN predictions during
> ALSModel.transform when a user and/or item factor is not present in
> the model. This can be useful in a production system, since it
> indicates a new user or item, and so the system can make a decision on
> some fallback to use as the prediction.
>
> However, this is undesirable during cross-validation, since any NaN
> predicted values will result in NaN results for the evaluation metric
> (for example when using RegressionEvaluator). This makes model
> selection impossible.
>
> Spark allows users to set the coldStartStrategy parameter to “drop” in
> order to drop any rows in the DataFrame of predictions that contain
> NaN values. The evaluation metric will then be computed over the
> non-NaN data and will be valid. Usage of this parameter is illustrated
> in the example below.
>
> Note: currently the supported cold start strategies are “nan” (the
> default behavior mentioned above) and “drop”. Further strategies may
> be supported in future.

Comment: I fixed the code according to your message - same mistake ( 
And i've checked dataset in pandas before converting it to PySpark - there are no NaNs. Thanks for your help!